# Can you suppress a single php file that won't parse/compile from showing as an error in Eclipse?

Tags: php, eclipse, eclipse-pdt

We are currently using Aptana for PHP and Eclipse for Java. While Aptana is built on Ecplise, it treats PHP files differently when they won't parse/compile. I'd love to use Eclipse for both, but I can't figure out how to suppress errors that should be ignored.

We use simpletest for all of our projects so we have it included in our "core" project and check it into SVN. Simpletest includes "test_with_parse_error.php", which is an invalid php file. In Aptana, the project does not show as having an error (nor does any php file) until you open it. At that point, you can see that the file has an error, but the project as a whole doesn't change (there is no "red X" on the directories where the file is located).

It almost appears as if Aptana treats folders as regular folders while Eclipse (galileo) treats all folders in a PHP project as "source folders". Is there a way to specify which folders should be considered "source" and which should not when looking for errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

starting with [eclipse PDT](http://www.eclipse.org/pdt/) 2.0, you can exclude resources from the build process using the [PHP Build Path configuration](http://files.zend.com/help/PDT/pdt.htm#configuring_build_paths.htm). this will also suppress warnings from the invalid file.

Comment: Unfortunately, this also excludes the entire file.  You may have a one line warning you want suppressed without losing the entire class in the file from the IDE build path.  This happens a lot with global functions provided by modules such as those available if you're running on apache like `apache_request_headers()`

Answer (score 0):

If Aptana is build on Eclipse, couldn't you just configure it to show the Java view? I could configure my Zend studio (also built on Eclipse and very much like Aptana) to show the Java view/workspace and work with it..

Comment: Aptana is built on old Eclipse. I want to use Galileo. I've tried the Aptana plugin, but that doesn't work well at all (don't remember what was wrong, but I know I gave up on it in utter frustration).